# I am looking for an algorithm to shuffle the first 25 bits of a (32-bit) int

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

All of the bit shuffling algorithms I've found deal with 16-bit or 32-bit, which means that even if I use only the first 25-bits of an int, the shuffle will leave bits outside. This function is in an inner loop of a CPU-intensive process so I'd prefer it to be as fast as possible. I've tried modifying the code of the Hacker's Delight 32-bit shuffle algorithm

```
x = (x & 0x0000FF00) << 8 | (x >> 8) & 0x0000FF00 | x & 0xFF0000FF;
x = (x & 0x00F000F0) << 4 | (x >> 4) & 0x00F000F0 | x & 0xF00FF00F;
x = (x & 0x0C0C0C0C) << 2 | (x >> 2) & 0x0C0C0C0C | x & 0xC3C3C3C3;
x = (x & 0x22222222) << 1 | (x >> 1) & 0x22222222 | x & 0x99999999;
```

but am having difficulty in doing some partly because I'm not sure where the masks come from. I tried shifting the number and re-shuffling but so far the results are all for naught. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

(I am using C but I can convert an algorithm from another language)

Comment: Can you explain what exact permutation of bits you want? "Shuffle" as I know it only makes sense on an even number of bits. By the way, you can fill it (the permutation) in here: http://programming.sirrida.de/calcperm.php and make it generate the code for you

Comment: Please advise:  By "shuffle", I assume you want the Least Significant 25 bits of an `int` rearranged in a seemingly random manner into the LS 25 bits.  Thus if x had 9 bits set in its 25 LS bit places, shuffle(x) would also have 9 bits set in the LS 25 bit places.

Comment: Each line has three pieces that are ORed together.  The first piece (eg: (x & 0x0000FF00) << 8) moves a set of bits up X positions. The second piece ((x >> 8) & 0x0000FF00) moves a set of bits down X bit positions.  The last piece grabs the remaining bits that aren't moving (x & 0xFF0000FF) and includes them in the result.  Assigning numbers and letters to bits this starts ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ012345 and becomes ABCDEFGHQRSTUVWXIJKLMNOPYZ012345, ABCDQRSTEFGHUVWXIJKLYZ01MNOP2345, ABQRCDSTEFUVGHWXIJYZKL01MN23OP45, and finally AQBRCSDTEUFVGWHXIYJZK0L1M2N3O4P5

Comment: Hey user2665197, please come back, I'm still curious about this

Comment: @harold: it looks like `0000000YXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA` -> `0000000MYLXKWJVIUHTGSFREQDPCOBNA` -> might be what's intended?  Call it a 26-bit shuffle since we know Z is 0 and will fall at the end of the shuffled bits.

Answer (score 1):

First, for the sake of evenness, we can extend the problem to a 26-bit shuffle by remembering that bit 25 will appear at the end of the interleaved list, so we can trim it off after the interleaving operation without affecting the positions of the other bits.

Now we want to interleave the first and second sets of 13 bits; but we only have an algorithm to interleave the first and second sets of 16 bits.

A straightfoward approach might be to just move the high and low parts of `x` into more workable positions before applying the standard algorithm:

```
x = (x & 0x1ffe000) << 3 | x & 0x00001fff;

x = (x & 0x0000FF00) << 8 | (x >> 8) & 0x0000FF00 | x & 0xFF0000FF;
x = (x & 0x00F000F0) << 4 | (x >> 4) & 0x00F000F0 | x & 0xF00FF00F;
x = (x & 0x0C0C0C0C) << 2 | (x >> 2) & 0x0C0C0C0C | x & 0xC3C3C3C3;
x = (x & 0x22222222) << 1 | (x >> 1) & 0x22222222 | x & 0x99999999;
```

The zeroes at the top of each half will be interleaved and appear at the top of the result.

Comment: LOL!  Apparently it took 11 years to get my first up vote on this.  I don't remember it at all.  I wonder if it helped the OP.